# What is the name of this painting of Mary and the infant Jesus?

Tags: life-of-jesus, virgin-mary, art

Since there exists no "Arts" site on Stack Exchange, I was inclined to come here to ask about this Christian work of art.

[image: Mother and Child]

Answer (score 8):

It is a copy or replica of a painting by Roberto Ferruzzi called ["Madonnina"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madonnina_%28painting%29) (commonly known as the "Madonna of the Streets").

The original has slightly different colours, different facial features, and it is in more of an impressionistic style, with thick visible brush strokes.

[image: The original painting by Ferruzzi]

I think the painting in the question is probably this following one, because the facial expressions are the same. However note that the cloak in this version is slightly different from the one in the question, and the door frame (?) on the right isn't clearly defined, so it may be yet another reproduction. This one is confusingly shown on the [Wikipedia page for Ferruzzi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roberto_Ferruzzi) (instead of the original), but it doesn't have any details of who made it. The actual version posted above has been retouched as neither Ferruzi's original nor this copy have a halo.

[image: The copy]